# numpy.minimum applied to pandas DataFrame and Series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I can use `np.minimum` and `np.maximum` using broadcasting such as:

```
a.shape = (100, 5)
b.shape = (5,)
c = np.mininum(a,b)
c.shape = (100, 5) # minumum elementwise between a and b
```

How would I do something like that, but working with pandas `DataFrame` and `Series` objects?

We cannot use the `value` attribute because we might lose the order of the columns. I want to take that order into account.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient way, but it will preserve your column order. You could just convert the `dataframe` and the `series` back to `numpy` arrays to perform the `minimum` operation, the convert that back to a `dataframe`. For example:

```
In [43]: df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5))

In [44]: sr=pd.Series(np.random.rand(5))

In [45]: df
Out[45]: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.435234  0.197012  0.364953  0.942068  0.657147
1  0.310736  0.721353  0.880256  0.140999  0.757069
2  0.840233  0.957006  0.785870  0.884206  0.625479
3  0.368817  0.386193  0.634408  0.895458  0.433639
4  0.804589  0.509249  0.124370  0.556714  0.895174
5  0.034010  0.519510  0.853540  0.192033  0.234513
6  0.262984  0.270159  0.673854  0.465467  0.906740
7  0.318838  0.518621  0.295384  0.596599  0.612002
8  0.804619  0.616971  0.309750  0.544413  0.013770
9  0.440933  0.857697  0.447541  0.266759  0.002859

In [46]: sr
Out[46]: 
0    0.807357
1    0.605892
2    0.328464
3    0.298340
4    0.424584
dtype: float64

In [47]: dfmin = pd.DataFrame(np.minimum(np.array(df),np.array(sr)))

In [48]: dfmin
Out[48]: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.435234  0.197012  0.328464  0.298340  0.424584
1  0.310736  0.605892  0.328464  0.140999  0.424584
2  0.807357  0.605892  0.328464  0.298340  0.424584
3  0.368817  0.386193  0.328464  0.298340  0.424584
4  0.804589  0.509249  0.124370  0.298340  0.424584
5  0.034010  0.519510  0.328464  0.192033  0.234513
6  0.262984  0.270159  0.328464  0.298340  0.424584
7  0.318838  0.518621  0.295384  0.298340  0.424584
8  0.804619  0.605892  0.309750  0.298340  0.013770
9  0.440933  0.605892  0.328464  0.266759  0.002859
```

Comment: I know that. I dont want the minimum dataframe element. I want the minimum value of dataframe compared to a series

Comment: Yes, actually it works thanks but if you have named columns (dataframe) and index (series), you have to sort them, then set index and columns to the newest DataFrame (`dfmin`). I don't like to do that, that's why I am looking for a more pandas friendly solution

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me what you're trying here as in numpy it won't work as the shapes cannot be broadcast:

```
In [188]:
a = np.random.randn(100,5)
b = np.random.randn(100)
c = np.minimum(a,b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-188-f59fe6dbb41e> in <module>()
      1 a = np.random.randn(100,5)
      2 b = np.random.randn(100)
----> 3 c = np.minimum(a,b)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,5) (100,)
```

If the dimensions were swapped then it works:

```
In [193]:
a = np.random.randn(100,5)
b = np.random.randn(100)
c = np.minimum(a.T,b)
c.shape

Out[193]:
(5, 100)
```

So for pandas the following would work:

```
In [191]:
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3))
np.minimum(df.T,s.values)

Out[191]:
         0         1         2         3         4         5         6   \
0 -0.462166 -0.753243 -0.857485 -0.783888 -1.058906 -1.782304 -2.866326   
1  0.586516 -0.735980 -0.857485 -1.005976 -1.015092 -1.782304 -2.866326   
2 -1.689027 -0.735980 -1.102960 -0.283301 -1.015092 -1.782304 -2.866326   

         7         8         9     ...           90        91        92  \
0 -0.967473 -0.824018 -0.633347    ...     0.022141 -0.794049 -0.522190   
1 -0.967473 -0.824018  0.066065    ...    -0.225902 -0.794049 -0.694794   
2 -0.967473 -0.824018  0.066065    ...     0.022141 -0.794049  0.278394   

         93        94        95        96        97        98        99  
0 -0.365531 -0.330756 -1.495789 -1.375226 -1.097268 -1.395099 -1.971968  
1 -1.805734 -0.330756 -1.495789 -1.375226 -1.097268 -1.395099 -0.543660  
2 -1.328497 -0.330756 -1.495789 -1.375226 -1.097268 -1.395099 -0.104600  

[3 rows x 100 columns]
```

So you need to transpose the df (if necessary) in order for broadcasting to work, then the series needs to flattened to a 1-D array which in this case can be done by calling `.values` attribute

Comment: Yes, it is the second case. I am editing my question. But the issue with your answer is that if you use `value` attribute, you cannot take in account the order of the dataframe's columns and the order of the series's column. So if you assume that `s` and `df` have not the same order, you will get a wrong result

Comment: I don't understand your last statement, a Series has no columns it's a 1-D array

Comment: Yes columns for dataframe, index for series. If the order is different between the dataframe's columns and the series' index, you've got a problem by using `values` attribute

Comment: but there is no pandas method that allows you to return the minimum like `np.miniumum`, also `np.minimum` does not care about aligning columns and indices here. You'd have to define a func yourself and `apply` it, also you need to add all this information to your question and to pose representative code to show your desired output including a series with an index in a different order to your df